# Percent on 100 tries?

Tags: percentages

If i know that something happens 50% In 1 try.

What is percent of Something to Happen at least once in 100 tries?

My friend told me that chances are 50% but i dont understand how that is possible?

could you explain with more details please

Comment: Have you tried calculating $P(\text{does not happen in 100 tries)}$? Then $P(\text{at least once in 100 tries})$ is just $1 - P(\text{does not happen in 100 tries)}$.

Comment: The rules for asking a question here are the same as on Stack Overflow. Please [see how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and add some context to your question: can you remember your friend's reasoning, and do you think it is true?

Comment: No i don't thik she is true because i am asking here

Comment: What's the probability it happens at least once in two tries?

Comment: Ok my question is if i know that in 1 try something happens 50% what is percent of this to happen at last once in 2 tries? 75% or more? or less? i don't know  because i am asking. is percentage of happening still 50%?

Comment: Happen at last or happen at least once?

Comment: leaaaast is correct sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider tossing a fair coin (equivalent to your problem). Now, the probability of getting no heads in 100 tosses is

$$P(\text{No Heads}) = \frac{1}{2^{100}}$$

Now, any other case other than this case has **at least one head**. Hence, since the total probability of all events occurring is one, we have

$$P(\text{At Least One Head}) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{100}}$$

This is much much bigger than 50%